# Is there Any Other Way to Disable the Headset?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I used the AudioManager Method: setWiredDeviceConnectionState to disable the headset on my device.  It worked fine until I came across some newer models and now it doesn't work.  I assume this is because the Hack doesn't work for these models.  Is there any upgrade to the previous hack or any other ways to disable the headset from the device?  I need to be able to play a tone via the In-Call_Speaker while a headset is plugged it.  Please Help!!!

This is the exception it gives when I run the activity:

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.raptorroboticstest-2/lib/arm64
W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setWiredDeviceConnectionState [int, int, class java.lang.String]
```

This is the method to disable/enable the headset:

```
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    try {
        Class<?> cl = Class.forName("android.media.AudioManager");
        setWiredDeviceConnectionState = cl.getMethod("setWiredDeviceConnectionState", new Class[]{Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class});
        //4 is for the headset with microphone 8 is for headset without microphone
        //0 is for off and 1 is for on
        setWiredDeviceConnectionState.invoke(manager, new Object[]{4, 0, "device"});
        setWiredDeviceConnectionState.invoke(manager, new Object[]{8, 0, "device"});
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but one of the top results when you search for the method name.

The method signature has changed. On Marshmallow and later there is an extra "address" parameter, that goes before the existing name String parameter.

The address parameter is used by bluetooth and USB devices, but an empty string will suffice for wired minijack headset/headphones.

[Lollipop and below](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java#L3014):

> public void setWiredDeviceConnectionState(int device, int state, String name)

[Marshmallow and later](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java#L3129):

> public void setWiredDeviceConnectionState(int type, int state, String address, String name)

Prior to Android Pie you could call setDeviceConnectionState() on [AudioSystem](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/AudioSystem.java) directly, which is what you will have to do if you need to specify the address for bluetooth/usb devices prior to Marshmallow. Like the AudioManager method, its signature changes beginning with Marshmallow, [adding the name String parameter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/media/java/android/media/AudioSystem.java#612) whereas before it [only included the address](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/media/java/android/media/AudioSystem.java#465).